# Matplotlib plot 24 hours with 1 hour intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I currently have this plot. Right now this plot shows an interval of 3 hours per ticks. I want to have all hours from 0:00 to 23:59 or back to 0:00 i.e. 00:00, 01:00, 02:00 ... 23:00, 23:59 or 00:00.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'toronto_time': ['2018-09-08 00:00:50',
                                    '2018-09-08 01:01:55',
                                    '2018-09-08 05:02:18',
                                    '2018-09-08 07:05:24',
                                    '2018-09-08 16:05:34',
                                    '2018-09-08 23:06:33'], 
                    'description': ['STATS', 'STATS', 'DEV_OL', 'STATS', 'STATS', 'CMD_ERROR']})
df['toronto_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['toronto_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot('toronto_time', 'description', data=df)
ax.set_xlim(df['toronto_time'].min()-pd.Timedelta(1,'h'),
            df['toronto_time'].max()+pd.Timedelta(1,'h'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inserting the line:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval = 1))
```

appears to have made all the difference, as it sets the tick mark frequency.

Full example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'toronto_time': ['2018-09-08 00:00:50',
                                    '2018-09-08 01:01:55',
                                    '2018-09-08 05:02:18',
                                    '2018-09-08 07:05:24',
                                    '2018-09-08 16:05:34',
                                    '2018-09-08 23:06:33'],
                    'description': ['STATS', 'STATS', 'DEV_OL', 'STATS', 'STATS', 
                                    'CMD_ERROR']})
df['toronto_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['toronto_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

plt.plot('toronto_time', 'description', data=df)
ax.set_xlim(df['toronto_time'].min()-pd.Timedelta(1,'h'),
            df['toronto_time'].max()+pd.Timedelta(1,'h'))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval = 1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

I've also added the `fig.autofmt_xdate()` line before the `plt.show()` to help format the hourly frequency to prevent overlapping timestamps on the x-axis.

This yields:

[image]